# Why is CreateFileA failing only when the executable is run under Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi, file-io, createfile

I wrote a simple `check_file_ref` function using WinAPI to check whether two paths reference the same file. The code is fine. It's compiled with Visual Studio 2017 in C (flag `/TC`).

The weird thing is `CreateFileA` (winapi) always fails when the executable is run under Visual Studio (ie execute without debugging), returning an invalid file handle. Otherwise, it works as expected when the executable is run outside of Visual Studio.

The working dir is the same in any case.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

/**
 * Check whether two paths reference the same file.
 * @param p1 File path 1.
 * @param p2 File path 2.
 * @return 0 same file, 1 different files, < 0 on failure.
 */
int
check_file_ref(char const * p1, char const * p2)
{
    if ( !p1 || !p2 )
        return -1;
    if ( p1 == p2 )
        return 0;
    if ( strcmp(p1, p2) == 0 )
        return 0;

    int ret;
    DWORD share, flags;
    HANDLE f1, f2;
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION s1, s2;

    ret = -1;
    share = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
    flags = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;

    f1 = CreateFileA(p1, GENERIC_READ, share, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, flags, NULL);
    f2 = CreateFileA(p2, GENERIC_READ, share, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, flags, NULL);

    if ( f1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s file, error %d\n", p1, GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    if ( f2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s file, error %d\n", p2, GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    if ( GetFileInformationByHandle(f1, &s1) == 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get %s file information, error %d\n", p1, GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }
    if ( GetFileInformationByHandle(f2, &s2) == 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not get %s file information, error %d\n", p2, GetLastError());
        goto cleanup;
    }

/*
    The identifier (low and high parts) and the volume serial number uniquely
    identify a file on a single computer. To determine whether two open handles
    represent the same file, combine the identifier and the volume serial number
    for each file and compare them.

    See
    https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle
    https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-_by_handle_file_information
*/
    ret = !(s1.dwVolumeSerialNumber == s2.dwVolumeSerialNumber
        &&  s1.nFileIndexLow == s2.nFileIndexLow
        && s1.nFileIndexHigh == s2.nFileIndexHigh);

cleanup:
    CloseHandle(f2);
    CloseHandle(f1);
    return ret;
}


int main()
{
    int ret;
    char workingDir[256];

    /* Both paths reference the same file.
       One is relative, the other absolute. */
    char * p1 = "hello.txt";
    char * p2 = "C:/Users/bro/source/repos/tests/x64/Debug/hello.txt";

    ret = GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, workingDir, sizeof(workingDir));
    printf("working dir: %s\n", (ret == 0 ? "err" : workingDir));

    /* Should return 0. */
    ret = check_file_ref(p1, p2);
    printf("p1: %s\n", p1);
    printf("p2: %s\n", p2);
    printf("check_file_ret ret %d ", ret);

    if      ( ret == 0 ) printf("(same file)\n");
    else if ( ret == 1 ) printf("(different files)\n");
    else                 printf("(error)\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Executable run under visual:

[CreateFileA fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCk1A.png)

Executable run directly from cmd line:

[CreateFileA works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q3cg.png)

Why is `CreateFileA` failing only when the executable is run under Visual Studio?

Comment: Check and compare GetCurrentDirectory (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) - GetModuleFileName is not for working directory.

Comment: Your `GetLastError` is not informative. You should use it *right after* the failed call.

Comment: You are calling `CreateFile` twice in succession then calling `GetLastError` after both calls complete. If there was a problem opening `f1`, the error code is lost

Comment: You are right, thank you! Working dir when run from visual is *C:\[..]\tests\tests* and directly is *C:\[..]\tests\tests\x64\Debug*

Comment: Govind Parma Indeed, well seen. Originally I didn't use GetLastError. I added it for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run an application from VisualStudio the default working directory is a project location, which is defined by VS macro `$(ProjectDir)`. You can change it by openning the project properties: Right click on the project in **Solution Explorer** and select **Properties** from the context menu. There select **Debugging** and change **Working Director**y property. For example, in your case the solution could be `$(OutDir)` or absolute path to the required location.

Comment: NEVER rely on relative file paths, ALWAYS use absolute file paths.  If you want to open a file whose path is relative to the app's own path, retrieve the app's path first via `GetModueFileName()` and then replace the filename portion as needed.